# How to add new string element to a list of strings?

Tags: string, list, haskell

In my homework, I want to write a function which adds a string to a list of strings, but I have no idea how to do it.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
AddToLS :: [String] -> String -> [String]
AddToLS ls s = (ls : s)
```

But this code doesn't even compile.

It should work like this:

```
AddToLS [] "one" =["one"]
AddToLS ["one"] "two" =["one","two"]
AddToLS ["one","two"] "there" =["one","two","there"]
```

Comment: It seems that you want to add your new element x at the end of the list. In Haskell, it is much more efficient to add it at the beginning of the list, this is just expression `(x:list)`. This is because the Haskell runtime system maintains only a pointer to the beginning of the list. Remember, lists can be unlimited, so in general you cannot maintain a pointer to the end of the list.

Comment: Appending to a list like this can produce a list that is very inefficient to iterate over. Consider using a different data structure (such as a [difference list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add an element of type string at the end, so, you can concat that element wrapped into a list and use the existing `(++)` function:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

so you will have to take your element and put it inside a list, like this:

```
AddToLS ["one", "two"] "three"
```

will be:

```
["one", "two"] ++ ["three"]
```

but you can define your own `concat` only for list of strings, as I can see, the arguments are flipped:

```
AddToLS :: [String] -> String -> [String]
addToLS = flip $ (++) . (:[])
```

that's equivalent to:

```
AddToLS :: [String] -> String -> [String]
addToLS ss s = ss ++ [s]
```

Comment: FWIW, I would not recommend the pointfree version to a beginner who does not know how to append an element to a list. The last one is shorter and obvious, the former required me to stop and think for a while.